# SSIS 2008 rs Pass variable parent to child

Tags: c#, ssis, ssis-2008

I have a VS 2008 Integrated Services Project using C#.
The Project has 2 packages:

Package.dtsx

```
variable MyStuff int 99

Execute package task with a file connection to Package1.dtsx
```

Package1.dtsx

```
variable MyStuff int 0

Package Configuration:
  Config Name - Configuration 1
  Config Type - Parent package variable
  Config String - MyStuff
  Target Object - MyStuff
  Target Property - Value

Script Task with a readwritevariable User::MyStuff
  public void main(){
    MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["MyStuff"].Value.ToString());
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
  }
```

I build the Script Task and the Solution. When I 'debug' the project the messagebox appears but with the value of the child variable. How do i get the value of the parent variable?

Comment: When you look at the output does it give a warning that the package could not populate from the parent?

Comment: The output shows 5 lines: Starting, executing, two lines of information stating package1 is attempting to configure from from the parent variable "MyStuff" and a finished Success line.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Variables collection and the VariableDispencer in Script Task(C#):

Variables var = null;

Dts.VariablesDispencer.LockForRead("User::ParentVariable");
Dts.VariablesDispencer.GetVariables(ref var);

String localVariable = var["User::ParentVariable"].Value.ToString();